# How to edit this string in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, string

I need once more a little help. I have this string:

```
/a href="/get.php file=hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip&amp;key=43e7ce13e9818c0b4c5737b7d061005606dfad5e"><b>HackMii Installer v1.0</b></a><br />"><b>HackMii Installer v1.0</b></a><br />
```

I only need, the part that is in " ", so in this example I would get:

```
(/get.php?file=hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip&amp;key=43e7ce13e9818c0b4c5737b7d061005606dfad5e)
```

I need to read this out and have to delete the not needed parts.
Can somebody help me out?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse the source of an HTML file. Can you provide more details? If this was the only string in question, you already solved your answer by pasting the result.

Comment: Why do I get visions of some stupid paperclip popping up when you say that?

Comment: @lornix You should join us in the [Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access). Clippy is a bot there. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried pasting the entire string into an editor?  notepad, notepad++, wordpad, word, openoffice, libreoffice...

Once there, you can edit and move around the characters however you wish.

THEN.. you can copy & paste the resultant command string into whatever you need.

Now, if you're looking to do it programmatically.. that's a WHOLE 'nother story.

---

### EDIT:

(gee, it *was* a request for how to do it programmatically...)

```
sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/' sourcefile > destfile
```

This would convert your source line into your desired output.

Of course, windows doesn't HAVE *sed*.  Maybe someone can gin up a PowerShell answer? Installing cygwin just seems overkill.

Comment: I do not want to do it manually, but it will happen automatically in a batch, so this is not an option!

Comment: you didn't SAY that... we're geeks, we're literal.  you said how... not how in a script or program...

Comment: sorry next time i try to say what I want '-.-

Comment: There is `sed` for Windows from GnuWin32 http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm and UnxUtils http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/.  The second one is a single .exe file which is easier to add to your `path` without installations.

Comment: Thanks, but is ist with C or C++ possible too? I don't want to install any software to reach my goal! I want to do it with programms which I can use with commandline. A simple C-File I convert would be better than to install sed.

Comment: Sure, there's a way to do it with C/C++/Perl/Php/Lua/Bash/Zsh/... and that's how 'sed' works.  @paradroid has a good solution, involving ONLY one program.  But if you `must`, I'd read the documentation for `regcomp`, `regexec`, `regfree`, if C++, try the `boost libraries`.  Awfully tedious method to accomplish what grabbing one program (see @paradoid's comment, previous) can do.  Reinventing the wheel isn't always the best path.  Maybe if you told us what you're REALLY trying to do, the big picture, we could have better answers.  But for now, @paradroid's comment is the best.